# ujson can not encode numpy array

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ujson

numpy array

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

ujson.encode

```
ujson.encode(x, ensure_ascii=False, double_precision=-1)
```

gives me error

```
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached
```

version info

```
ujson 1.33
python 3.4.3
```

It seems to be that ujson can not encode numpy array and gives confusing error message.

By the way, where can I find the documentation of ujson. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to convert any numpy arrays to regular lists before jsonification. Hence,

```
ujson.encode(x.tolist())
```

should work (Python 3.5.3; ujson 1.35).

ujson documentation: https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson

Btw, there's an [issue](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/221) for what you described.